# Error in deleting record from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView control with the following markup:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvGroups" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ShowFooter="True" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" CellSpacing="1" BorderWidth="2px"
            BackColor="White" CellPadding="3" GridLines="None" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="11px"
            DataKeyNames="GroupId" OnRowDeleting="gvGroups_RowDeleting">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Row">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal ID="litRowNumberNormal" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal ID="litRowNumberFooter" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("Title")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddTitle" runat="Server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
                            Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="11px" BorderColor="Black" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditTitle" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid"
                            BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="11px" BorderColor="Black" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" UpdateText="Save" CancelText="Cancel"
                    EditText="Edit" HeaderText="Edit">
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#669900" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5A49A7" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemStyle BackColor="#FFC080" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:CommandField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" ID="btnRemove" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid"
                            BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#FFC080" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="11px" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkRemove" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle BackColor="LightCoral" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5A49A7" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#669900" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

model of this grid is a List of Group class.
Group class is as follows:

```
public class Group
{
 public int GroupId {get; set; }
 public string Title {get; set; }
}
```

GroupId is primary key of my table.
When I press Delete button, I get the following error:

> **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>
>   Parameter name: index**

my RowDeleting event handler codes:

```
protected void gvGroups_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkRemove;

    List<int> ids = new List<int>();


    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvGroups.Rows)
    {
        chkRemove = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("ChkRemove");
        if (chkRemove.Checked)
        {
            ids.Add(Int32.Parse(gvGroups.DataKeys[gvRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
        }
    }

    if (ids.Any())
    {
        GroupService.DeleteGroupById(ids);
    }

    this.BindGroups();
}
```

Comment: `RowDeleting` handler is used to delete a *current* row. You need to add "button" outside the `GridView` and write the code to delete selected (checked) rows.

Comment: No. In this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20734/Customary-Functions-of-GridView-in-ASP-NET-3-5 the author added delete button inside the GridView.

Comment: which line of code is throwing the exception ?

Comment: may surprise, but no line! after clicking on delete button, the error occure! stack trace: [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index]
   System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) +104
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleDelete(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex) +322

Comment: @MohammadAram : what is your binding code , are you sure that your datasource for gridview contains GroupId ? set a breakpoint on the ids.Add line and check both row.index and gridview.DataKeys

Comment: yes, all items have GroupId, i set breakpoint on the first line of RowDeleting event but debugger does not stop on breakpoint!

Comment: no , set it on the ids.Add line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another work we can do is changing CommandName property of "Delete" button to anything other than "Delete" and handle it in RowCommand event,
"Delete" command is default CommandName for firing RowDeleting event of GridView control.

Answer (score 0):

the code looks correct but the event chosen is not . as @AVD mentioned [RowDeleting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting.aspx) event is for `per row` situation where each `row` has its own `Delete button` :

> Occurs when a row's Delete button is clicked, but before the GridView
>   control deletes the row

all you need is to add a `btnRemove_Click` event and put your code there .

Comment: thanks mohsen. but how the author of this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20734/Customary-Functions-of-GridView-in-ASP-NET-3-5 do that?

Comment: I should check the code myself . you can use one of answers here untill you figure it out what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the multiple delete add a button called multiple delete outside the gridview and handle the onclick event, in the event handler delete the number of items that are selected like below

```
public void DeleteEverything(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this function is to delete the selected items based on the checkbox
        CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("SelectAllCheck");
        // to get the Checkbox status in the header rows
        if (chkAll.Checked == true)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)//to get all rows in that particular page
            {
                string Delete = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);
                //Cells[3] is the column to get one by one rows cells[3] columns where you should keep your primary keys and in visible state
                Bal_add.Delete(Delete);
                i++;
            }
            Response.Redirect("Information.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            int j=0;
            foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkSel = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("SelectCheck");
                if (chkSel.Checked == true)
                {
                    string Delete = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[3].Text);
                    //Cells[3] is the column to get one by one rows cells[3] columns where you should keep your primary keys and in visible state
                    Delete(Delete);

                }
                j++;

            }
            Response.Redirect("Information.aspx");
        }

    }

public void Delete(string UserEmail)
        {
            obj_add = new add();
            string QueryString;
            QueryString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Admin_raghuConnectionString1"].ToString();

            obj_SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(QueryString);

            obj_SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_DeleteDataProcedure");
            obj_SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            obj_SqlConnection.Open();

            obj_SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmail", UserEmail);//here @UserName is the variable that we declare in the stored procedure
            obj_SqlCommand.Connection = obj_SqlConnection;
            SqlDataReader obj_result = null;

            obj_SqlCommand.CommandText = "usp_DeleteDataProcedure";
            obj_result = obj_SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            obj_SqlConnection.Close();

        }
```

You can delete according to your primary key in the stored procedure Hope this helps :D